# Rails Tutorial Ch. 9 Exercise 6: Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am trying to write tests and application code to redirect users who are already signed-in to the root_path if they try to CREATE a user or visit the NEW user path.

Here are the tests I have written in user_pages_spec.rb:

```
describe "for signed in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "using a 'new' action" do
        before { get new_user_path }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end

      describe "using a 'create' action" do
        before { post users_path }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end         
  end
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :unsigned_in_user, only: [:create, :new]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
     @user = User.new(user_params)
     if @user.save
      sign_in @user
          flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
          redirect_to @user
     else
          render 'new'
     end
  end

  private
    # Before filters

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation)
    end

    def unsigned_in_user
      puts signed_in?
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are already signed in." unless !signed_in?
    end
end
```

The `puts signed_in?` returns false.  I am assuming this is the problem because I would expect it to return true.  Here are the errors after running the tests using rspec.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Failures:

  1) User pages for signed in users using a 'create' action 
     Failure/Error: before { post users_path }
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param not found: user
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:52:in `user_params'
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20:in `create'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:162:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages for signed in users using a 'new' action 
     Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:158:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Within the sessions_helper.rb file:

```
def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

In spec/support/utilities.rb:

```
def sign_in(user, options={})
  if options[:no_capybara]
    # Sign in when not using Capybara.
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
  else
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
end
```

Comment: Post the code for the signed_in? method. Since it is returning something you didn't expect, the problem probably lies there.

Comment: added. I am new to rails but I am wondering if the fact that signed_in? is defined in sessions_helper.rb and I am trying to use it in the users controller (and not the sessions controller) poses a problem..

Comment: In certainly would cause a problem unless you include the SessionHelper in your ApplicationController. Did you do that?

Comment: Another possible problem I see is that you create a user instance with the user_params, but you don't define it anywhere: @user = User.new(user_params)

Comment: I have it in there I just removed it from the post so it wouldn't be terribly long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34808/discussion-between-ikegawataro-and-amb110395)

Comment: It could be that the save action is failing validations and re-rendering the new action.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  The problem appears to be that  this: before { sign_in user } is not signing in a user because signed_in? is returning false.  I added the method in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were you able to get your tests to pass?

In case you weren't, I had the same problem as you today, and was able to get the tests to pass by making two changes to the tests - passing a `user` hash when POSTing, and using the `no_capybara` option on the `sign_in` method, since `get` and `post` are not capybara methods and I think RSpec doesn't behave as we might expect if we switch from capybara to non-capybara methods within the same test.

```
describe "for signed-in users" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

  describe "using a 'new' action" do
    before { get new_user_path }      
    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
  end

  describe "using a 'create' action" do
    before do
      @user_new = {name: "Example User", 
                   email: "user@example.com", 
                   password: "foobar", 
                   password_confirmation: "foobar"} 
      post users_path, user: @user_new 
    end

    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice!  I added the no_capybara: true option to the first test and now both pass.  I didn't pass a user hash for create but it now passes.  I guess that is not a requirement... i.e. from the microposts tests: describe "submitting to the create action" do
          before { post microposts_path }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, because a user hash would only be needed if Rails actually carries out the create method, which is what we're trying to prevent. Thanks - we're both filling in each other's gaps :)

Answer (score 3):

Same answer as najwa, but I used the FactoryGirl **user** with the Rails *attributes* method to avoid duplication:

```
describe "using a 'create' action" do
  before { post users_path, user: user.attributes }

  specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
end
```

Helps to keep the data decoupled from the test code.